# SQL Server Reporting services - Connection closed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a problem with SQL Server Reporting Services. I got this error message by enabling verbose logging on the server:

> Reporting Services error
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: An
>   error has occurred during report processing.
>   ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
>   An error has occurred during report processing.
>   ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'dsMyDSNAme'.
>   ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.XmlDP.XmlDPException:
>   Failed to execute web request for the specified URL.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

I've googled and nobody else had this specific problem. I'm suspecting a networking issue somewhere. How can I trace the problem?

Comment: This sounds like a SSL issue are you accessing data from app a with http hopping to a process requiring SSL? Or maybe you are accessing and endpoint in code requiring https using http.

Comment: Hi @lrb. Thanks for the feedback. I've narrowed the problem down to a specific web method in the web service. So the bindings are correct as far as I can see, but something in this web method is causing the problems. Thanks.